# google earth vs. google map api: For a specific environment

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I am about to start a new project which will be used about 80% through non-mobile devices like desktops and laptops and 20% through mobile devices. And yes, I want to use KML capabilities too, use JQuery for all my JS work and do not want users to download any plugin separately.

I have implemented two projects already using Google Maps API blissfully unaware of Google Earth API. Now I started reading about the two and nothing is clear about what is the right choice. I even referred to posts on this site so please do not mark this as a duplicate.

Google's documentation on Google Earth API states:

Welcome to the developer documentation for the Google Earth API. The Google Earth Plugin and its JavaScript API let you embed the full power of Google Earth and its 3D rendering capabilities into your web pages. Just like in the Google Maps API, you can draw markers and lines—but in 3D!

Well, with that statement from the horse's mouth, it confused me even more. Why would anyone use Maps API then. Can someone with experience in both these tools, give some definite statements for the specific environment I have described? The earlier posts do not give convincing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe when I last looked Google Earth support in the browser is implemented through the use of Web GL which will severely limit your browser support and I think eliminate mobile devices.

While Earth may be prettier Maps is more performant and arguably stable and I would think it would be the logical choice for you in this case.

[This page contradicts some of this but requires the use of a plugin which you specify you do not want.](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index)

For information on using KML layers with the Maps API see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml).

Comment: You are right about the contradictions. That is what confused me. I was comfortable with Google Maps API (except I had not used KML with it) until I came across this very documentation. Ignorance is truly bliss. Thanks anyway. Upvoting  your answer. Lets see what else comes, if anything.

Comment: Updated with a relevant KML link, it's fairly trivial to implement although the size of the KML file can be an issue. Also remember to set the MIME type for KML files if you're self hosting. This has tripped me up before.

Comment: Wondering if this is a technically correct statement: Google Earth API provides more features than Google Maps API and provides a 3d view of the earth but needs the plugin to be installed.

Comment: Potentially I would add that it is also more resource intensive from a client side perspective, and that third party library support (marker clustering, labeling etc) is less comprehensive.

Comment: Are you saying that Google Earth API has less third-party library support? That would be useful information to know because I would have expected the other way around. Answer accepted.

Comment: I wouldn't quote me on that, but as a gut feeling yes. The maps API is in use across far more sites and thus logically that would be the case.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. The last statement, though not "quotable," is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I understand the situation.

There were two similar but different products co-existing for a long time:

- 2D Maps born on web
- 3D Earth born on desktop and brought to the web as plugin.

This caused a lot of confusion.
It would be beneficial to unite the two, but that only became possible recently with WebGL.

Last week Google released new Maps having Earth integrated.
Unfortunately, I was not able to find any documentation about this integration yet.

But, still, my answer is: use Maps and eventually you'll get Earth for free.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Upvoted your answer. Since you have looked at the new Google MAPS, did you find any reference to the updates or changes, if any, to the Google Maps API Version 3 as a result of the new Google MAPS? I did not find any but that does not make sense.